# Django Unitest Checking Value Of Template Variable

Tags: django, django-unittest

Suppose I have {{registered}} variable in template. I wrote a piece of test:

```
def nice_test():
     response = self.client.post(reverse('app:register'), {'username': 'dupa'}
```

and there I want to check value of variable registered in response. How to do it ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The response from the test client has access to the template context used.

```
def nice_test():
     response = self.client.post(reverse('app:register'), {'username': 'dupa'})
     self.assertEqual(response.context['registered'], '<expected value>')
```

Here is a reference to the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Response.context

> class Response
>   ...
>   context
>   The template Context instance that was used to render the template that produced the response content.