# Non-existing template variables in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

What is the best practice for either testing or making sure that all your template variables are in fact existing.

Assume that we have the following template

```
<html>
  <div>{{ existing_object.non_existing_attribute }}</div>
</html>
```

We have an existing object. So we can't really test the response context like in the following answer: [Django Unitest Checking Value Of Template Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27190359/django-unitest-checking-value-of-template-variable)

There is `string_if_invalid` as described in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled). But that should only be used for debugging purposes.

Any insight on how to best avoid this would be helpful!

**Edit**: Let's assume that the non-existing attribute is a bug. Ie I misspelt the variable, because of this it's showing up as an empty string.

**Edit2**: This question has a lot better answers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7854404/554903

Comment: Maybe you can create a template tag passing an object and then with python's hasatrr check if the object has  the attribute you want to check

Comment: I think, the how depends on what you want to do if the attribute does not exist. E.g. do you want to show a default value or don't display the `div` at all? You can also just check `{% if existing_object.non_existing_attribute %}`, but that does not distinguish non-existing and non-truthy attributes.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Well, ideally I would like it to throw an error to be honest. I expected the attribute to exist on that object, but it doesn't. In python outside of templates this would get me an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the proper way to do this would be to have test specific settings and set a value for the setting [`string_if_invalid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django). So set the value to something like `INVALID`. And when you get the return of the response make sure that the template does not contain `INVALID`.

As the settings will only be available in your testing environment you'll never run the risk of getting the word `INVALID` into production.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the builtin template tag `default_if_none`.

`{{ object.attribute|default_if_none:"Nothing" }}`

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. The question deals - given I understand it correctly - with ensuring that all variables in the template are passed by the view.